# start and stop time to schedule and run all the threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, time

I have the the below try method and I need to figure out how to get the start and stop time to schedule all the threads and print out the time.

I know how to get the actual run time, just can't figure out how to print the time it took for the thread to start. Thanks.

```
void run() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Code goes here.....

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
    System.out.println("Execution time is " + formatter.format((endTime - startTime) / 1000d) + " seconds");        
}
```

Comment: Please provide detail example, I think your problem is that, you want to measure time taken from starting the thread by start to actually run method is executed. Correct?

Comment: TIP: When measuring time, use `System.nanoTime()`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MyThread extends Thread {

    ThreadLocal<Long> timeAtStart = new ThreadLocal<Long>;

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        //override start method and print time when start method was invoked
        timeAtStart.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long timeToRun = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
        System.out.println("Starting thread took " + formatter.format((timeToRun - timeAtStart.get()) / 1000d) + " seconds");

        //Code goes here.....

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Execution time is " + formatter.format((endTime - timeToRun) / 1000d) + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Thanks.